# jQuery Ajax RestAPI Cross-domain

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I spent my day to read about the said topic but i cannot make this code work.
can someone help me this work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var url = "http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BDO.json?jsoncallback=?";

     $.getJSON( url).done(function( data ) {
          alert('done'); // i have codes here to manipulate the return
      }).error(function( data ) {
          alert('error');
          console.log(data);
      });     
});
```

(you may test the url, and its 100% working. but my code is not :( )
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your service is not returning JSONP. Until it starts returning jsonp, there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get a jsonp response sending the callback name you need to return something like

```
mycallback({"stock":[
   {"name":"Banco de Oro",
    "price":{"currency":"PHP","amount":83.8},
    "percent_change":0.24,
    "volume":2100730,
    "symbol":"BDO"}],
    "as_of":"2014-03-17T15:46:00+08:00"})
```

Otherwise it will be a normal JSON response.

Because you need to wrap your JSONP in a call to a function like [this](http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=processJSON&tags=monkey&tagmode=any&format=json) example.

Using something like this once you return a wrapped response it will work

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://phisix-api.appspot.com/stocks/BDO.json?callback=?',
    dataType: 'JSONP',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Take a look at this fiddle doing a JSONP request to the flick services.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LRpqq/4/) (updated)

Comment: the very last portion of your answer is not needed when using jquery. simply replace `callback=mycallback` with `callback=?` jquery will define the callback for you.

Comment: Which one the function?

Comment: Yes. if you define a function in this way and use dataType JSONP, jquery will never call the success function.

Comment: so doing this there is no need to create the function and simply jquery will add one  for it?

Comment: Yes, assuming the service reads the "callback" url parameter. If mycallback is instead hardcoded into the service, then you'd need to use the jsonpcallback option.